# What is the mean of bold words

Tags: meaning-in-context

All, I read this paragraph from a read. But not sure about the exactly meaning. please help me to understand it .thanks.

> Grant focuses on making it fun for beginners to learn Ubuntu Linux.
>   **If you're just an ordinary user, who's not sure what's going on behind Windows or Mac OS X's glossy interfaces and you don't really
>   care either, this is the Ubuntu book for you**.

Grant is a linux book author.

Answer (score 3):

The author is saying that Grant's book is well-suited for someone who has experience using a different operating system (Windows or Mac OS X) and only interested in learning what's necessary to accomplish typical Windows/Mac tasks on Ubuntu, rather than the technical details of how it works.

In other words, Grant's book is a good introduction to Ubuntu for the casual computer user.